# Getting values for all submatches alone leaving the match in regexp -inline

Tags: tcl

I am trying to get submatches alone in a regexp inline ..

```
set a "class-map id 400
   channel-rate normal
   class-map id 670
   channel-rate normal
   class-map id 456
   channel-rate normal"

puts [regexp -inline -all {class-map\sid\s([0-9]+)} $a]
```

which gives a list like {class-map id 400} 400 {class-map id 670} 670 {class-map id 456} 456

how to get submatches alone in a list ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the *varlist* feature of the `foreach` command:

```
set ids {}
foreach {match submatch} [regexp -inline -all {class-map\sid\s([0-9]+)} $a] {
    lappend ids $submatch
}
set ids    ;# => 400 670 456
```